# Facing the issue while creating the DynamoDB using the cloud formation template. And also how to define the attributes Boolean, List & Map in YAML CF

Tags: amazon-web-services, yaml, amazon-dynamodb, aws-cloudformation

1. I'm trying to create DynamoDB table using the cloud formation template, I'm getting the error

"One or more parameter values were invalid: Number of attributes in KeySchema does not exactly match number of attributes defined in AttributeDefinitions (Service: AmazonDynamoDBv2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ValidationException; Request ID: CB468V0TU7G4JM4VKV52H3Q583VV4KQNSO5AEM"

Template:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Resources:
  oeautomatorteamconfigTable:
    Type: AWS::DynamoDB::Table
    Properties:
      TableName: oeautomator-team-config
      AttributeDefinitions:
        - AttributeName: "active"
          AttributeType: "B"
        - AttributeName: "devResolverGroups"
          AttributeType: "S"
        - AttributeName: "excludeAgingList"
          AttributeType: "B"
        - AttributeName: "excludeNoncontrollableList"
          AttributeType: "B"
        - AttributeName: "excludeReroutedList"
          AttributeType: "B"
        - AttributeName: "fleetId"
          AttributeType: "S"
        - AttributeName: "managerLogin"
          AttributeType: "S"
        - AttributeName: "metricsDashboardLinks"
          AttributeType: "S"
        - AttributeName: "orgName"
          AttributeType: "S"
        - AttributeName: "simFolderId"
          AttributeType: "S"
        - AttributeName: "supportResolverGroups"
          AttributeType: "S"
        - AttributeName: "teamName"
          AttributeType: "S"
      KeySchema:
        - AttributeName: "teamName"
          KeyType: "HASH"
      TimeToLiveSpecification:
        AttributeName: "ExpirationTime"
        Enabled: true
      ProvisionedThroughput:
        ReadCapacityUnits: "5"
        WriteCapacityUnits: "5"
    DependsOn:
      - DynamoDBQueryPolicy
  DynamoDBQueryPolicy:
    Type: "AWS::IAM::Policy"
    Properties:
      PolicyName: DynamoDBQueryPolicy
      PolicyDocument:
        Version: "2012-10-17"
        Statement:
          - Effect: "Allow"
            Action: "dynamodb:Query"
            Resource: "*"
      Roles:
        - Ref: "oeautomatorteamconfigTableQueryRole"

  oeautomatorteamconfigTableQueryRole:
    Type: "AWS::IAM::Role"
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: "2012-10-17"
        Statement:
          - Effect: "Allow"
            Principal:
              Service:
                - "dynamodb.amazonaws.com"
            Action:
              - "sts:AssumeRole"
      Path: "/"
```

2. How to define the attribute types BOOLEAN, LIST and MAP in a CF template for DynamoDB

Please help me solving this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How to define the sortKey in this example

Answer (score 0):

Your `KeySchema` only has `teamName`. Thus, your `AttributeDefinitions` **can't have anything else** then `teamName`, unless you define local or global secondary indices, or use sort key as well. DynamoDB is **schema-less**.

So it should be:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Resources:
  oeautomatorteamconfigTable:
    Type: AWS::DynamoDB::Table
    Properties:
      TableName: oeautomator-team-config
      AttributeDefinitions:
        - AttributeName: "teamName"
          AttributeType: "S"
      KeySchema:
        - AttributeName: "teamName"
          KeyType: "HASH"
      TimeToLiveSpecification:
        AttributeName: "ExpirationTime"
        Enabled: true
      ProvisionedThroughput:
        ReadCapacityUnits: "5"
        WriteCapacityUnits: "5"
    DependsOn:
      - DynamoDBQueryPolicy
  DynamoDBQueryPolicy:
    Type: "AWS::IAM::Policy"
    Properties:
      PolicyName: DynamoDBQueryPolicy
      PolicyDocument:
        Version: "2012-10-17"
        Statement:
          - Effect: "Allow"
            Action: "dynamodb:Query"
            Resource: "*"
      Roles:
        - Ref: "oeautomatorteamconfigTableQueryRole"

  oeautomatorteamconfigTableQueryRole:
    Type: "AWS::IAM::Role"
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: "2012-10-17"
        Statement:
          - Effect: "Allow"
            Principal:
              Service:
                - "dynamodb.amazonaws.com"
            Action:
              - "sts:AssumeRole"
      Path: "/"
```

Comment: Could you help me, on how to use the sortKey in this example?